# Namespace for array field in node-soap client (Node.js)

Tags: xml, node.js, soap, wsdl, node-soap

How to configure node-soap client set namespace for array not only for objects?

My params for 'sendPatient' method:

```
params = {
        patientCard: {
          patient: {
            firstName: 'test',
            lastName: 'test'
          },
          identifiers:
            {
              code: "123456789",
              codeType: 1
            }
        }
      };
client.sendPatient(params, ...)
```

node-soap produce:

```
<soap:Envelope                                                     
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"           
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"            
  xmlns:tns="http://xxx/patient/api/"     
  xmlns:bi="http://xxx/base/info/build/">              
  <soap:Header></soap:Header>                                      
  <soap:Body>                                                      
    <tns:sendPatient                                               
      xmlns:tns="http://xxx/patient/api/" 
      xmlns="http://xxx/patient/api/">    
      <tns:patientCard>                                            
        <ns1:patient                                               
          xmlns:ns1="http://xxx/patient/">
          <ns1:firstName>test</ns1:firstName>
          <ns1:lastName>test</ns1:lastName>                      
        </ns1:patient>                                             
        <ns1:identifiers                                           
          xmlns:ns1="http://xxx/patient/">
          <ns1:code>123456789</ns1:code>                         
          <ns1:codeType>1</ns1:codeType>                           
        </ns1:identifiers>                                         
      </tns:patientCard>                                           
    </tns:sendPatient>                                             
  </soap:Body>                                                     
</soap:Envelope>
```

and it's works, but I need to send array of identifiers, not only one, so when I put array

```
params = {
        patientCard: {
          patient: {
            firstName: 'test',
            lastName: 'test'
          },
          identifiers: [
            {
              code: "123456789",
              codeType: 1
            }, {
              code: "987654321",
              codeType: 2
            }
          ]
        }
      };
```

node-soap produce:

```
<soap:Envelope                                                     
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"           
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"            
  xmlns:tns="http://xxx/patient/api/"     
  xmlns:bi="http://xxx/base/info/build/">              
  <soap:Header></soap:Header>                                      
  <soap:Body>                                                      
    <tns:sendPatient                                               
      xmlns:tns="http://xxx/patient/api/" 
      xmlns="http://xxx/patient/api/">    
      <tns:patientCard>                                            
        <ns1:patient                                               
          xmlns:ns1="http://xxx/patient/">
          <ns1:firstName>test</ns1:firstName>                                     
          <ns1:lastName>test</ns1:lastName>                
        </ns1:patient>                                             
        <ns1:identifiers>                                          
          <ns1:code>00100180035</ns1:code>                         
          <ns1:codeType>1</ns1:codeType>                           
        </ns1:identifiers>                                         
        <ns1:identifiers>                                          
          <ns1:code>00100180035</ns1:code>                         
          <ns1:codeType>1</ns1:codeType>                           
        </ns1:identifiers>                                         
      </tns:patientCard>                                           
    </tns:sendPatient>                                             
  </soap:Body>                                                     
</soap:Envelope>
```

and I get error from server for `<ns1:identifiers>` part

```
`[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace prefix "ns1" at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [17,25]]`
```

What am I doing wrong? Can I somehow add `xmlns:ns1="http://xxx/patient/"` to `<soap:Envelope>` tag or configure node-soap to add it for arrays too (not for only simple objects)?
P.S. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 19):

Published temporary solution [on Github](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/issues/672#issuecomment-110848132)

after createClient patch wsdl definitions

```
soap.createClient(wsdl, options, function(err, client) {
      client.wsdl.definitions.xmlns.ns1 = 'http://xxx/patient/'
      client.wsdl.xmlnsInEnvelope = client.wsdl._xmlnsMap()

      //works now
      client.sendPatient(...)
});
```

Comment: Hi. I am working with Microsoft Dynamics With Node-soap. I am not able to access my NAV Web service using nodejs. Do you have any idea about how to consume from Microsoft Dynamics NAV Web service?

Comment: fyi for devs with autocomplete - client has both:
`client.wsdl.xmlnsInEnvelope` and `client.wsdl.xmlnInEnvelope` (that's `xmlns` vs `xmln`) if you autocomplete the one without an `s`, you're going to be very frustrated.

Answer (score 1):

In typescript you can access to private wsdl as [Swarthy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30763624/4264508) comments, but appending the namespace directly:

```js
client['wsdl'].xmlnsInEnvelope += 'xmlns:ns1="http://xxx/patient/"';
client['wsdl']._xmlnsMap();
```